Applying Find & Replace method to MSWordDoc.Range somehow didn't cover the whole document
I tried to replace certain string using wildcards, with VBA.
However, text in Shapes, with the same format specified in FindText, somehow survived the Replace method.
I've tried RngToFind.WholeStory as well, same result. How can I apply Find & Replace to literally everything within the document?
Btw, if I do the Replace manually, the result is fine and don't have the problem above. So I think the key is the declaration of Range object.
Dim MSWordApp As Object, MSWordDoc As Object, RngToFind As Object

Set MSWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set MSWordDoc = MSWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\123.docx")
Const wdReplaceAll As Long = 2
Const wdSaveChanges As Long = -1

Set RngToFind = MSWordDoc.Range
With RngToFind.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Execute FindText:="Doc*.??", MatchWildcards:=True, ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Set RngToFind = Nothing
MSWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
MSWordApp.Quit
Set MSWordDoc = Nothing
Set MSWordApp = Nothing


In addition to textboxes, you need to consider whether you need to replace content in headers, footers, footnotes & endnotes.

You need to iterate over shapes (Word macro sample):
Option Explicit

Sub Macro4()
  Dim v As Variant
  For Each v In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    With v.TextFrame.TextRange.Find
      .Text = "Doc*.??"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next
End Sub

